# Quantlib - BlackVariancesurface

Tags: python

Below is my code for using Quantlib  blackvariance surface. But it complains. can you advise? In this function I am calling the Blackvariance function with 6 variables

---

```
from QuantLib import *

# global data
todaysDate = Date(24,September,2013)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
settlementDate = Date(24,September,2013)
riskFreeRate = FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.0025, Actual365Fixed())
# option parameters
exercise = EuropeanExercise(Date(23,December,2013))
payoff = PlainVanillaPayoff(Option.Call, 170.365)
# market data
underlying = SimpleQuote(170.365)
volatility = BlackConstantVol(todaysDate, TARGET(), 0.13538, Actual365Fixed())
dividendYield = FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.0227, Actual365Fixed())

dc=ActualActual()
eurexCal=Germany.Eurex
print eurexCal
dateVec=[]
strikes=[]
blackVolMatrix=[]
vol=[]
for i in range(10):
  dateVec.append(Date(24, October, 2013)+Period(i, Months))
  strikes.append(170+i*10)
  vol.append(0.1+i/10)

def create_matrix(m, n):
    return [[0.1]*n for _ in xrange(m)]

blackVolMatrix = create_matrix(10, 10)

#for x in range (10):
#    for y in range(10):
#        blackVolMatrix[x,y]=0.1

volsurf=BlackVarianceSurface(settlementDate,eurexCal,dateVec,
                             strikes,blackVolMatrix,dc)
```

***I have added the 6th argument. ********************

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chandra/Software/snotes/test4.py", line 39, in <module>
    strikes,blackVolMatrix,dc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/QuantLib/QuantLib.py", line 3371, in __init__
    this = _QuantLib.new_BlackVarianceSurface(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_BlackVarianceSurface'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    BlackVarianceSurfacePtr(Date const &,Calendar const &,std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,std::vector< Real,std::allocator< Real > > const &,Matrix const &,DayCounter const &,BlackVarianceSurface::Extrapolation,BlackVarianceSurface::Extrapolation)
    BlackVarianceSurfacePtr(Date const &,Calendar const &,std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,std::vector< Real,std::allocator< Real > > const &,Matrix const &,DayCounter const &,BlackVarianceSurface::Extrapolation)
    BlackVarianceSurfacePtr(Date const &,Calendar const &,std::vector< Date,std::allocator< Date > > const &,std::vector< Real,std::allocator< Real > > const &,Matrix const &,DayCounter const &)
```

Comment: By my count that type requires 6, 7 or 8 arguments, but your code only passes in 5.

Comment: volsurf=BlackVarianceSurface(settlementDate,eurexCal,dateVec,
                             strikes,blackVolMatrix,dc)  
it still gives same error. ( it was a typo I did not include the day count)

Comment: Then the *type* of arguments is incorrect. Please [edit] your qusetion to correct that missing argument at least.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to initialize your calendar is

```
eurexCal = Germany(Germany.Eurex)
```

after which the vol surface builds correctly. `Germany.Eurex` is just an enumeration to distinguish between different markets; you'll have to pass it to the `Germany` constructor to obtain an actual `Calendar` instance.

Comment: Luigi, your suggestion worked out perfectly. My sincere thanks to you.